# How to exclude mentions in the Twitter streaming API

Tags: cocoa, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I am using the Twitter Streaming API since I need to get all posts on the home timeline as well as lists and hashtags the user is following. However, this also returns mentions (which do not appear on the timeline) is there a way to exclude these from the streaming API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it is not yet possible to ignore @mentions in the Twitter Stream, so I just had to manually sort and remove @mentions after receiving the data.